# Making Java button dynamically?

Tags: java, button

I am new to Java and I am working on a project where depending on number of files in a directory,
buttons will be created respectively. Each button will have a customized right click context menu.

How can I achieve this or is this feasible?
I just want to know the approach to do this.

Comment: It will depend on the frame work you are considering to use...

Comment: have you tried anything so far? do you already have a project and can you share some code of that?

Comment: I just want to know the approach to do this.

Comment: is it a LibX button? a SWT button? an AWT button? why would you have a popup menu (context menu) on a button?

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you may try:

While you iterate your directory/file list (or other process that will determine the button creation), you can generate (create an instance of) a new button (JButton), I assume you know how to use `new`, and put it on your form / panel.

However, most of the time, layout would become an annoying issue here.
Thus, you may try to use [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) to handle this.
It will help you a lot in putting your stuffs in a tidy and convenient way.

Try this approach and when you have a specific coding-part question, you can try to search the existing solution in SO (StackOverflow) or if it doesn't exist, you can ask that specific code-related question.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but this was the question actually what you suggested.

Comment: if you can't proceed on trying this approach, then that means you need to learn the basic through googling first..